# EF Migration cannot find the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a context like this.

```
namespace Database
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class salon_database_test : DbContext
    {
        public salon_database_test()
            : base("FangConnection")
        {
            Setup();
        }
}
```

When I run `Enable-Migrations`, as default, it creates a `Migrations` folder. However, it only has 1 file `Configuration.cs` instead of 2 (Configuration and InitialCreate). I have error in the Configuration file saying that `The type name 'salon_database_test' does not exist in the type 'System.Data.Entity.Database'`

 Below is the Configuration file

```
namespace Frontend_Database.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Database.salon_database_test>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(Database.salon_database_test context)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I miss?

Comment: Have you build the solution before running migration?

Comment: @WeryNguyen yes i did

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @tbone No. I don't know what caused this problem

Answer (score 0):

After you enable migrations, you need to add the initial migration and then apply it:

```
add-migration "InitialCreate"
update-database -verbose
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#generating

Comment: When I try this I get a "failed to build" error (because of the type name does not exist error noted in the original post)

Answer (score 0):

Your current Project is called **"Database"** and this name is conflict with `System.Data.Entity.Database`

**The solution is remove `"Database"` word**

**Old code:** `internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Database.salon_database_test>`

**New code:** `internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<salon_database_test>`